# Can't enable intel driver 82845g/gl (brookdaleg) chipset

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics

My desktop has intel  82845g/gl (brookdaleg) chipset can't enable intel driver. Runs well with VESA.

But when I try to enable the intel driver the xlog shows an error that no device detected and boots in text mode what should i do to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I recently answered a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53667/fixing-display-issues-on-intel-82845gl-in-natty/53698#53698) with this chipset.

In summary - it sort of works in  Natty - but you'll need to add a grub boot option of `i915.modeset=0` and install Unity 2D.

The OP for that question found that Lubuntu worked much better than Unity-2D.

I suspect that the OP for this question was using either Maverick or Lucid.  Both of these version of Ubuntu had serious i8xx issues - the Kernel team blacklisted the i8xx series - they only ran with the seriously degraded VESA mode.

There are suggested workarounds for i845 for [Maverick](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Bugs/Mavericki8xxStatus) and [Lucid](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/541492) - but in my experience - upgrade/fresh install to the Lubuntu 11.04 (or possibly Xubuntu 11.04) - remember to use the grub-option I described.