# How to get a driver for an Intel 82852/855GM?

Tags: 11.04, intel-graphics

My niece's laptop had Ubuntu 9.04 and supported this video card perfectly, Compiz effects, games, movies, everything..., but she wanted Iphone support so I installed the new Ubuntu 11.04, but for my surprise the video card is not supported, no Compiz effects, and it's using the Vesa drivers.

I was trying to find a way to use the intel drivers and have all the effects running again. I found and follow some tutorials, installed patched drivers and create a xorg.conf to use the intel drivers but its very unstable and buggy, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I hope someone can help me resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same graphics in my laptop - I'm afraid that the i8xx series are not supported for the Unity interface.

You can test this by running

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

The unity 2D interface I found also an issue - quite slow with graphic artefacts as well.

I'm using Lubuntu 11.04 with the `xcompmgr` composite manager.  This works very well for my i855 laptop.

Below is a link for someone I've helped in the past with the slightly older graphics set.  He similarly had to boot with one of the i915.modeset parameters.  He concluded, like me to stick with Lubuntu.

---

Linked Question:

1. [Fixing display issues on Intel 82845GL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53667/fixing-display-issues-on-intel-82845gl-in-natty)