# Which Ubuntu version will work best with 845G motherboard?

Tags: performance

I have been working with Ubuntu version 11.04 and I have noticed that it is a lot slower than xp. Like, windows take more time to open. Processes take more time to complete. Even surfing the net is slower. I did some research and found out that an older version might be better than this version. Also, if other linux distributions would be faster and better for my machine, please tell me which ones/ I am giving my system specs-
chipset - Intel Brookdale-G i845GEV
motherboard - 01/25/2005-i845G-W627-6A69VM4YC-00
video adapter - Intel(R) 82845G/GL/GE/PE/GV Graphics Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53667/fixing-display-issues-on-intel-82845gl/53698#53698) with regards to the i845 and unity/unity 2D.

The OP himself confirmed that Lubuntu was the recommended distro for your graphics type.

You should note, the chief reason for this is that intel have dropped support for the i8xx series of graphics chipset.  The support is legacy only with mainly stability fixes.  Thus the more newer interfaces such as Unity will not work correctly (no 3D acceleration).

Lubuntu has moved on for the better in v11.10 - I would warmly recommend you try this newer version rather than the slightly older Natty version of Lubuntu.