# Intel 845GL graphics driver issues

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fixing display issues on Intel 82845GL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53667/fixing-display-issues-on-intel-82845gl)

The screen divides into 4 segments after Ubuntu 11.4 or 11.10 is installed on the HDD.  This issue does not show up when running from CD.

Is there a quick way to tell Ubuntu 11.10 to use the same driver used from CD?

The issue is exactly same as reported here: [Fixing display issues on Intel 82845GL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53667/fixing-display-issues-on-intel-82845gl)

But none of the answers posted there solved the issue.

Any help for a newbe?