# Desktop only visible on small portion of the screen on old Dell Inspiron 1100

Tags: 12.04, drivers, dell, resolution

I have an old dell inspiron 1100 laptop and I installed ubuntu 12.04.2 dual boot with windows xp. Everytime I log into ubuntu, the screen appears always on the left hand corner, never full. This laptop has the capacity to 1024 x 768, but always says 640 x 480. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but still the same errors. I thinking of installing 14.04 but I have the feeling that the same error will occur. I even tried downgrading to 7.04, but error with intel.

I even did a bios flash from A22 to A29, and nothing changed.

```
VGA compatible controller (0300):
Intel Corp 82845 G/GL (BROOKDALE)
Subsytem: dell Device (1024:0149)
Kernel modules: intelfb, i915
```

I have no idea what else to do. Please need guidance and step by step instructions. I like the feel of Ubuntu 12.04 as a desktop.

```
Intel pentium 4 2.20ghz
level 2 Cache: 512kb
System memory: 640 mb
video controller: intel 845GL
UMA video memory: 1 MB
Audio Controller: Sigmatel 9750
Modem controller: PCTel 2304WT
```

Comment: @user68186 Driver problems are not being solved by another flavor. Thus, the question you mentioned isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @the_Seppi Look at the specs. It has **less than 1GB of RAM** and old Intel video. It does not need the cutting edge driver. Intel 845GL drivers should be included in any recent kernel. I would go for spanking new intel driver if we were dealing with the Broadwell graphics that are just beginning to come out. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/53667/fixing-display-issues-on-intel-82845gl

Comment: HI I installed Lubuntu 14.02 but still have the small screen resolution. How do I fix this issue? I did a dual partition with windows xp and Lubuntu. Screen looks great in windows xp, but too small on upper left corner.

Comment: Instead of putting new information in comments and answers, please edit and update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still able to use system with it being in corner, or is it too small.

If you can use it, you may want to check to see if there is a proprietary driver available to install for your Intel Graphics.

In your version of Ubuntu, I think it in software sources and last tab is drivers. If it finds display driver, enable it. Then reboot.

**Edit**

Commenter may be right, I didn't notice the low video/system ram. You may want to use something lightweight like Lubuntu, possibly Xubuntu

Comment: HI I installed Lubuntu 14.02 but still have the small screen resolution. How do I fix this issue? I did a dual partition with windows xp and Lubuntu. Screen looks great in windows xp, but too small on upper left corner.

Comment: Did you ever try the driver suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

As you're using an Intel Graphics card/chip, you can try installing more apt drivers using Intels Linux Graphics Installer. Here's a step-by-step instruction:

1. Go to the Intel Open Source [website](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/) and download the latest Graphics installer for Ubuntu. Download the installer for the correct architecture (32-/64-bit). I assume you'll need the 32bit one.
2. The downloaded file will have a .deb file extension, meaning it's a software package. When you double click it, the Ubuntu Software Center should open up, prompting you to confirm the installation. Click <kbd>Install</kbd> and enter your password.
3. After the installation finished, you should have a new item somewhere in your menu/dash with the name *Intel Linux Graphics Installer*. Click it.
4. Follow the steps described by the installer. You may have to enter your password again.
5. If it's able to find a driver, it'll install it. If this succeeded, close the program and reboot your computer and you may have working graphics.

---

For such an old and weak computer, Unity (the desktop of Ubuntu) could be too demanding. You may try a more lightweight flavor like [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net). In Lubuntu, instead of USC, a program called GDebI will open to install .deb packages. The procedure will be the same, though.

Comment: last I knew Intel driver install from that route trashed the system. Did something change?

Comment: This can happen with any driver, not just with Intel's installer. I've never made any bad experience with ILGI.

Comment: HI I installed Lubuntu 14.02 but still have the small screen resolution. How do I fix this issue? I did a dual partition with windows xp and Lubuntu. Screen looks great in windows xp, but too small on upper left corner.