# ubuntu 11, maximum resolution is a low 1024 x 768

Tags: graphics, resolution

I just installed ubuntu 11 and the maximum resolution that it will let me set it at is 1024 x 768.  My graphics are onboard, its the intel 82845g.  Trying to increase the resolution and support the video more smoothly.

UPDATE:

```
user1@pc1:~$ xrandr | grep maximum
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 2048 x 2048
user1@pc1:~$ gtf 1280 1024 59.9

  # 1280x1024 @ 59.90 Hz (GTF) hsync: 63.49 kHz; pclk: 108.70 MHz
  Modeline "1280x1024_59.90"  108.70  1280 1360 1496 1712  1024 1025 1028 1060  -HSync +Vsync

user1@pc1:~$ xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_59.90"  108.70  1280 1360 1496 1712  1024 1025 1028 1060  -HSync +Vsync
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  20
  Current serial number in output stream:  20
user1@pc1:~$
```

Comment: No need to paypal. Please provide more details.
Could you provide the output of this command line on a terminal:
 xrand -q   and this one :   lspci | grep VGA    and this one:   sudo lshw -C video          
What Laptop/computer model do you have?
what Ubuntu version you installed: 11.04 or 11.10?
Is it an external monitor or a the laptop screen? If an external monitor, how do you plug it? VGA, DVI, HDMI?

Comment: this is ubuntu 11.10, it's a monitor that's about 5 years old, but it runs high resolutions fine in windows xp.  I have it hooked up through VGA cable - It's a gateway PC, I got the machine for free when someone else upgraded - I don't know the model number - it's probably 5 years old easy.  It has only PCI slots, and one AGP.  I would really like to be able to run atleast 1280 x 1024 resolution.  I don't mind buying a video card.

Comment: Here is the output.

user1@pc1:~$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 2048 x 2048
VGA1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0*
   800x600        60.3     56.2 
   848x480        60.0 
   640x480        59.9 
user1@pc1:~$

Comment: user1@pc1:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE Chipset Integrated Graphics Device (rev 01)
user1@pc1:~$

Comment: user1@pc1:~$ sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] password for user1:
  *-display              
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE Chipset Integrated Graphics Device
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f0000000-f7ffffff memory:ffa80000-ffafffff
user1@pc1:~$

Comment: Ok I see. That's likely a driver issue.
Can you specify the highest resolution you can get in Windows XP?

Comment: The output of xrandr shows that the highest mode available for your screen is 1024X768 with the current Intel graphics driver.
Normally you have to add another mode (e.g: 1280X1024) to Xorg.
Meanwhile try forcing the desired resolution if you're sure your monitor handles it, with this command :    
xrandr -s 1280x1024

Comment: i just installed a geforce nvida 6200 video card and it won't go any higher... still stumped on this.  If I can't get it to work at a higher resolution I will ditch linux all together

Comment: Installed a Nvidia 6200? Did it prompt you to install proprietary software or not?
Besides, do you login in Unity or Unity 2D?

Answer (score 3):

Use **xrandr** to make sure that the new mode can fit within the maximum framebuffer size

```
xrandr | grep maximum
```

Use **gtf** to create a mode line

```
gtf 1280 1024 59.9
```

(59.9 is the refresh rate)
Add the new mode using xrandr

```
xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_59.90"  ............
```

replace the above dots (........) by what the gtf command gives you after the mode is created. It should be something like this:  ***106.29  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 901 904 932  -HSync +Vsync***

Add this newly added mode to the desired output (VGA/LVDS etc  - ***VGA*** in your case)

```
xrandr --addmode VGA 1280x1024_59.90
```

Choose the new mode

```
xrandr --output VGA --mode 1280x1024_59.90
```

---

See a similar question: [Can't enable intel driver 82845g/gl (brookdaleg) chipset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23518/cant-enable-intel-driver-82845g-gl-brookdaleg-chipset)

Merely speaking, It also indicates that installing Lubuntu solves the issue.

For your **Nvidia card**: see solution : [Display resolution with NVIDIA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66858/display-resolution-with-nvidia)